# Skrollr : Output looks different although I use the same code as the example

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax, skrollr

I'm following the first basic example on the Skrollr's website.
Here is their example: http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/docu/1.html

So, I use View Source and copy the code into my codepen.io here to learn and twinkle with it: http://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/JYvxOv

Now, here's the super strange mysterious thing: although the code is identical (the responsive code part is the only part I didn't copy), the blue bar on the "WOOOT" doesn't show up in mine. Also, their example has a vertical scrollbar while mine don't.

What's happening here? I didn't see any CSS or links to any CSS file in their example, so I assume perhaps they have some backend server technology that changes that example file somehow on the fly and give it extra CSS properties and other code magically which I don't know of.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s = skroll.init();
});
```

```html
<div id="skrollr-body">
  spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>spacer
  <br>
  <div id="foo" data-0="background-color:rgb(0,0,255);" data-500="background-color:rgb(255,0,0);">WOOOT</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, its there, but you've added some rotational stuff beyond that original example.  Go to your codepen, and scroll the html output screen slowly.

Here's the extra stuff you added:

```
<div data-0="background-color:rgb(0,0,255);
             transform[bounce]:rotate(0deg);" 
     data-top="background-color:rgb(255,0,0);
               transform[bounce]:rotate(360deg);">
    WOOOT
</div>
```